# adding images in the markdown interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to add a local image by adding this line in my %md cell.

It used to work well for Jupyter notebooks.

Does anyone have any idea what might be needed to get this to work on zeppelin notebooks. I have tried searching a ton online but can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. You don't have to setup an additional webserver as you can use the embedded webserver of zeppelin. All you have to do is to store the images inside the Apache Zeppelin webapp folder to embed local images with the markdown interpreter, as those are accessible from outside.

For example when your zeppelin is installed in /opt, just create a directory for the images (but keep in mind that this directory will be deleted everytime you restart Zeppelin):

```sh
mkdir /opt/zeppelin/webapps/webapp/app/markdownImages
```

and store the images there. You can embed them now with the markdown interpreter:

```
![bla](app/markdownImages/test.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to install Apache webserver and put your images in the /var/www/html folder then you can display the images through localhost:

```
%md

<hr />
![](http://localhost/myImage.png)

<hr />
![](http://localhost/myImage.png)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the help of webserver